# Order Confirmation is Very slow

Tags: prestashop

When trying to make any payments, It is taking 10 min to complete the payment.

After 5 mins I am receiving email and after 5 more mins I am redirected to Order Confirmation Page.

I tried all possible ways, can some one help me with this please ?

Answer (score 0):

The cause can be many, and the only way to know is debugging, but a common problem here is the sending mail, specially when the admin use the mail alerts module with a large list of emails address to be notified, if you have turned on this module, just disable it and try again.

An extra recommendation is, use SMTP instead of php mail.

Comment: I am using SMTP for sending email, Also, I tried disabling email alerts, even after disabling  email alerts I have not seen any improvement in the performance. Please advice.

Comment: We have a module to improve this task, which separate the sending email in the main process significantly increasing response times: https://www.rolige.com/en/prestashop-modules/notifications-automatic-emails/ultra-fast-email-sender-optimizer-23.html